# Azure QnA Maker Cognitive Service: Connect Knowledge base Programmaticaly to QnA Maker

Tags: bash, azure, curl, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

If I create a new knowledge base via the Azure portal it requires me to connect an existing QnA Maker Service to it.

However there does not seem to be a programmatic way to do this:

The QnA Maker REST API provides calls to create and publish a knowledgebase, however there's no information on how to specify the QnAmaker service to use:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/qnamaker/knowledgebase

I create and publish a knowledge base using roughly the following operations, but cannot seem to find any way to associate the newly created knowledge base with an existing QnA Maker Cognitive Service.

Have I either misunderstood the relationship between these two resources, or is this a gap in the documentation and if so, how can I connect a new kbase to an existing QnA Maker service instance?

```
function create_kb () {

 userId=$(curl -s -X POST "${api_create_end_point}" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ${subscription_key}" \
  --data-ascii "${body}" | jq -r '.userId')

}

function get_user_kbases () {

  kbId=$(curl -s -X GET "https://${endpoint}/qnamaker/v4.0/knowledgebases" \
    -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ${subscription_key}" \
    --data-ascii "" | jq -r '.knowledgebases | .[] | select(.name == "govbotkb").id')
  echo "${kbId}"
}


function publish_knowledge_base () {

  echo "Publishing the knowledgebase ${kbId} ..."

  publish_result=$(curl -s -X POST "https://${endpoint}/qnamaker/v4.0/knowledgebases/${kbId}" \
    -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ${subscription_key}" \
    --data-ascii "${body}")

  echo "${publish_result}"

}


function get_knowledgebase_details () {

   echo "Getting knowledgebase details ..."
   echo curl -v -X GET "https://${endpoint}/qnamaker/v4.0/knowledgebases/${kbId}" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ${subscription_key}"
   kbase_details=$( curl -s -X GET "https://${endpoint}/qnamaker/v4.0/knowledgebases/${kbId}" \
                   -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ${subscription_key}" \
                   --data-ascii "{body}"
                  )
    echo "${kbase_details}"

}
```

Comment: What programming language is that?

Comment: BASH. It's just wrapping the curl REST API calls.

Comment: Is myanswer acceptable?

Comment: Hi Kyle,  haven't had a chance to test this in my pipeline. Let me  give it a go and get back to you. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a subscription key into each of those API calls, including when you create the knowledge base. The subscription key comes from your QnA service, and so it is used to identify your service and connect the knowledge base to it.